# Summing and finding non-zero entries of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, gsl

I need to do two things to an array in C:

1. Summing its entries.
2. Finding the position of all non-zero entries.

I am doing both by looping through each element of the array. E.g.

```
int sum_array(int a[], int num_elements)
{
   int i, sum=0;
   for (i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
   {
     sum = sum + a[i];
   }
   return(sum);
}
```

For task 2, I will be checking if the entry is 0. If not, add its position to another array to mark it as non-zero.

**Question**

Are there more efficient ways of doing these?

I am also using the GNU Scientific Library (GSL), if there are more efficient solutions in there. I just started C recently.

Comment: Your approach is reasonable. Try to start optimizing only if you run into performance problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments from Gregor, EvilTeach and some of my own googling, my approach is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

For part 2, you don't really have to do any work.

if the value in the array is zero, then it would evaluate to false.  Any non-zero value would evaluate to true.  So you can iterate through the array any time, and ignore the zero values.

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically need to find the positions of the non-zero entries in the array.